# How to work on git branches created by cvsimport?

Tags: git, cvs, cvsimport

My [man page for `git cvsimport`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsimport) says

> You should never do any work of your own on the branches that are
>          created by `git cvsimport`.

There's something here I don't understand.  I'm migrating a project from CVS to git.  Once I've imported the branches, where am I supposed to do my work?
Do I need to clone from the imported repo into another repo?

Can someone explain what the warning in the man page means, and what is going on here?  If I can *understand* what's happening, I can probably figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is more about *multiple* imports or even export (ie round-trip updates, with `git cvsexportcommit`)

If you work on branches imported by the git cvsimport tool, you could change its history (with a rebase for instance), making any *subsequent* import impossible.

I suspect this is similar to the [git svn caveat](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_caveats) section.
Cloning the imported repo into another one is usually the recommended practice, but only if you intent to do other imports from CVS.

Comment: Thanks VonC -- where might this be documented?

Comment: @NormanRamsey I didn't find a direct documentation, but I suspect the risk behind modifying a branch used by `git cvsexportcommit` is similar to the one used by `git svn`